# Using curves to exert a force over time - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a an AnimationCurve which allows me to add keyframes with a certain value and time. Im making a dash for my player which exerts a force over a specified time. To make this more customizable i want a curve that can change the amount of force over time. But im not very good at using curves and have a couple problems:

- How can i limit the keyframes so they can only be between 0 and 1 on the time? (I could probably go through all keyframes and check if there above a cirtain time if so move them back, but im wondering if theres a better way)
- How do i use the curve to adjust the force over time

If its of any benefit, heres the code for the dash and the curve field (its in a custom editor)
Field:

```
GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
_forceOverTime = EditorGUILayout.CurveField("Dash Force over Time", _forceOverTime);
if (GUILayout.Button("Reset", GUILayout.MaxWidth(80))) ResetCurve(ref _forceOverTime);
GUILayout.EndVertical();
```

Dash:

```
private void DashUpdate() {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift) && dCooldown <= 0) {
        dashing = true;
        dashDir = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        dCooldown = dashCooldown;
        dashCount = dashTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your code for using the curve (-> [`AnimationCurve.Evaluate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve.Evaluate.html))? Otherwise I'm confused what you are asking ... if you don't even use the curve in code so far .. why do you think the curve is the best option?

Comment: someone already answered, but before using the curve i was just applying a constant force

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EditorGUILayout.CurveField, you can pass an argument to specify a rectangle with the ranges for the curve. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.CurveField.html).

You can then use `_forceOverTime.Evaluate(t)`, to get the value of the curve at time `t` and use it in your force or velocity calculations for your RigidBody.

Hopefully this answers your question!